# Error to running "CIRIquant" function in CIRIquant package at python Language

Tags: rna-seq, python

"[CIRIquant](https://ciri-cookbook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/CIRIquant_1_installation.html)" is a Python package for detecting Circular RNA. I installed "CIRIquant" through the below command in terminal:

> pip install CIRIquant

My Linux distribution is Ubuntu 16.04 and my python version is Python 2.7.12. After installing, I got the below message:
“Installing collected packages: numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, pysam, PyYAML, argparse, numexpr, CIRIquant
Successfully installed CIRIquant-1.1.2 PyYAML-5.1.1 argparse-1.2.1 numexpr-2.6.9 numpy-1.16.4 pysam-0.15.2 scikit-learn-0.20.3 scipy-1.2.2”

So, When I call CIRIquant for running its function in Terminal, I got the below message in Terminal:

```
CIRIquant: command not found
```

Now, I don't know what is my problem?
I appreciate it if anybody shares his/her comment with me.
Best,

Comment: did you activate your virtualenv environment? `source ./venv/bin/activate`

Comment: Dear @zorbax, No. I didn't activate virtualenv. is it necessary? because I didn't install CIRIquant from the source code. could you please guide me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I try this as a regular user on our Ubuntu 16 LTS system, I end up with `~/.local/bin/CIRIquant` from the pip install, so maybe just add that directory to your path:

```
$ export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
$ CIRIquant -h
usage: CIRIquant [-h] [--config FILE] [-1 MATE1] [-2 MATE2] [-o DIR]
                 [-p PREFIX] [-t INT] [-a INT] [-l INT] [-v] [--version]
                 [-e LOG] [--bed FILE] [--circ FILE] [--tool TOOL]
                 [--RNaseR FILE] [--bam BAM] [--no-gene]
```

Comment: Dear @Jesse I set export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH" and I could run CIRIquant -h  but now when I run e.g: ls  then the system give me below comment: "ls: command not found" and error related to PATH environment variable

Comment: Make sure you kept your old `$PATH` as part of the new string, rather than having *only* the new path (which is what that sounds like to me).  You can `echo $PATH` before and after the change to check it.  You should still see things like /usr/bin in there afterward.